# HTTPS implementation in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, https, passenger

I was trying to implement https on a subdomain. I have included [SSL_requriment](https://github.com/rails/ssl_requirement) plugin

my application controller has two statements:

```
  include SslRequirement
  ssl_required if ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == "production"
```

I have generated key, csr and crt and specified this in apache config file:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app.my_app.com
    DocumentRoot /home/me/my_app/production/current/public
    </VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName app.my_app.com
    DocumentRoot /home/me/my_app/production/current/public
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /home/me/my_app/production/shared/plusrev.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/me/my_app/production/shared/plusrev.key
    </VirtualHost>
```

Still my subdomain is not redirecting to https. Anything I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.

Use

```
 gem 'grosser-ssl_requirement', :require => 'ssl_requirement'
```

in you gemFile. Here is the [gem guide](https://github.com/grosser/ssl_requirement)

In your application controller:

```
 include SslRequirement
 ssl_required :all if ENV["RAILS_ENV"] == "production"
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this post:
http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/05/configuring-rails-3-https-ssl/

Answer (score 0):

There are no actions passed to ssl_required. However I guess you want to add

```
def ssl_required?
  true
end
```

to your controller so https is required for all actions by default.

The plugin API isn't obvious so look into the code.